# @media query display block not working in @emotion/react

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a style like this

```js
 //inside page.jsx
 
export function Page() {
  return (
      <div css={container}>
          <div css={header}>
            <div css={horizontal}>
                <Menu
                    mode="horizontal"
                >
                    <Menu.Item>
                        <Link href="#>
                            <a>Menu A</a>
                        </Link>
                    </Menu.Item>
                </Menu >
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  )
}
 
 
 //inside styles.js
 export const horizontal = css`
    display: none;
    @media (min-width: 720px) {
      display:block;
    }
`

export const header= css`
     height: 10%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
     padding: 0 20px;
     background-color: white;
     position: sticky;
     top: 0;
     z-index: 1;
`
```

When testing the browser with a size less than 720px its works as intended the content is invisible because of display none, but when the browser size is back to more than 720px it's not working at all (not going back to visible).

if I replace the Menu component with another component the style is working properly (when less than 720px = invisible and when more than 720px = visible). Also, it can work with the Menu component if removing display flex in the header style.

I'm a bit confused about what going on here.